# How to expand a div to its content width WHEN it is larger than its parent?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to build a carousel view. For that I have a parent div, representing the viewport, a content div, holding the items to be shown in the view, and an unknown number of divs, representing the items shown in the view.

```html
<div id="viewport">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent and the items size is known beforehand but I want the content size grow with the items. With the following CSS, the items are displayed inline as I want, but the content's width will expand only until it matches its parent width.

```css
#viewport {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

How can I make the content div expand until it matches its children size? Here is a JSFiddle for what I'm saying: http://jsfiddle.net/j4LnB/ (the red border is showing the content's size).

Comment: have you tried `min-width:400px` instead of width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block;` on the #content-div

Answer (score 2):

Using `min-width` instead of `width` on the viewport div should do the trick. This allows the content div to expand to the full children width.

```
#viewport {
   position: absolute;
   min-width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j4LnB/1/

Comment: This makes the viewport expand as well, and I want that only the content div to expand. The viewport size must be fixed as it is used to hide some of the content (see the overflow:hidden). If there is another way to hide the content without this viewport div it works for me. Thanks for the answer anyway :)